# sam cli with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sam-cli

I am attempting to complete the resume challenge using aws and ran into a little issue. when inputting 'sam build'. I get this error message 'Error: PythonPipBuilder:Validation - Binary validation failed for python... which did not satisfy constraints for runtime: python3.9. Do you have python for runtime: python3.9 on your PATH?'.

so I realized the python version I'm running is Python 3.10.7 and I'm assuming this must be the issue. is it possible to change the python version in my build template to the version I'm actually running?

Thanks for any responses

Comment: can you expand on what is the "resume challenge"?

Comment: https://cloudresumechallenge.dev/docs/the-challenge/aws/

Comment: thats a link to what im talking about. its supposed to be a great way to get your foot in the door for a cloud computing career. so basically you create an outstanding resume that should get a lot more attention than the rest.

Comment: i ended up figuring it out. i downloaded python version 3.9 and changed PATH to that version since now i have 2 python versions installed on my machine. ran 'sam build' again and it worked, the build was successful!